# Populating timetoday columns with vars

Tags: datatable, jscript, timeofday

Why does this work:

```
table.setCell(0,0,[18,12,31]);
```

and this doesn't

```
strTime="18:12:31";
time = strTime.split(":");
table.setCell(0,0,time);
```

the column has been defined by

```
table.addColumn('timeofday','Time');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a

```
strTime.split(":");
```

the result is an

```
Array [ "18", "12", "31" ]
```

which contains strings, not integers. Yet, the `timeofday` type [requires an array of four numbers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?csw=1#methods):

> If the column type is 'timeofday', the value is an array of four
>   numbers: [hour, minute, second, milliseconds].

To obtain an array of `Number`s, you could use

```
strTime.split(":").map(Number)
```

which applies the `Number`-function to each string element. This returns a Number object. The `map` applies it recursively to each element of the array.

Comment: That works! Life can be so simple once you know.
Thanks a lot!